# Installing Jupyter Ganymede kernel on M1 Macbook pro + Cannot run program "/usr/bin/env bash"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel

I am working on getting the Ganymede kernel installed in my Jupyter environment. Followed the instructions from the [docs](https://github.com/allen-ball/ganymede). Mine is an M1 Macbook pro.

when I execute the following command:

```
$ java -jar ganymede-2.1.2.20230910.jar -i
```

I get:

```
ERROR [    main] Install                                  : Cannot run program "/usr/bin/env bash": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/env bash": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at ganymede.install.Install.getOutputAsString(Install.java:288)
    at ganymede.install.Install.run(Install.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
    at ganymede.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
    at ganymede.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:60)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Any workaround to get this working?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is the program name; `bash` is an argument to it, not part of its name. Find whatever is trying to run `env bash` as a single word and fix that thing.

Comment: To be very clear, MacOS **does** ship both `/usr/bin/env` and `bash`, so as long as you have a normal PATH, the code works just fine when it's correctly interpreted as two separate arguments; the issue is whatever's misusing ProcessBuilder, treating both words as if they were part of the executable name, whereas only the first one is in fact such a name.

Comment: Think about filing a bug report at https://github.com/allen-ball/ganymede -- the author is in a position to fix this; we aren't. (We can help _you_ fix it, if you want to get into ganymede's source code, but if you aren't willing to do that you're interacting as a user rather than as a developer, and Stack Overflow isn't really the right place)

Comment: ...also, reading the source to https://github.com/allen-ball/ganymede/blob/c582159143121422f88aabd1b8642a160b6456da/ganymede/src/main/java/ganymede/install/Install.java#L62, I see they've got a `which` function defined. You don't need `/usr/bin/env` when you have `which`, as you can just do a PATH lookup directly yourself.

Comment: (...what's _really_ weird is that from the code on github -- if you're running a binary that genuinely corresponds to the source that's published -- the line in question should be running `python3`, not running `/usr/bin/env bash` at all -- but this is something that a debugger is probably the best way to investigate)